# Почему не передаются куки при переходе на новый url из Angular?

Tags: angularjs, cookie, redirect

```
angular.module('app',['ngCookies'])
.controller('controller',['$cookieStore','$window',function ($cookieStore, $window) {
  $scope.test = function () {
    ...
    $cookieStore.put('Authorization', token.access_token);
    $window.location.href = url;
  };
}]);
```

Такой код не передаёт cookies, в дебагере нет соответствующего request header и бэкэнд не получает авторизацию, помогите плз

Comment: а почему он должен передавать? посмотрите где сохранены куки и на какой адрес вы переходите

Comment: Блин, Grundy, спасибо, ты открыл мне глаза. Реально надо было обновить ангуляр, использовать $cookie вместо $cookieStore и указать путь и домен для которых записываем куки.

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли ответ, добавьте его и отметьте как выбранный